# How to get Url Parameter in websphere commerce bean?

Tags: java, request, websphere-commerce

I am trying to get URL, tried following two methods but got 'null' commandContext. Tried some other also but got null every time.

```
  Object req = commandContext.getRequest();
 com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.HttpControllerRequestObject req1 = (com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.HttpControllerRequestObject) req;
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpReq = req1.getHttpRequest();
ses = httpReq.getSession();


 HttpServletRequest request =
 ((com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.HttpControllerRequestObject) this 
 .getCommandContext()
 .getRequest())
 .getHttpRequest();
```

Don't quite get what I am doing wrong, would please anyone help?

I want to catch parameters present in url that user hit in specific scenario.

For instance,

```
https://webAddress/MyForm?item=someitem&qty=1
```

I need to get 'item' and 'qty'.

Answer (score 3):

It been a little late, but I think it will be helpful to others.
To get the query parameters in the controller command from the url, You can follow the either of the approach mentioned in this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.tutorial.doc/tutorial/ttd15.htm)  
or you can try like following , Get the request properties and fetched the value by using query parameter name

```
TypedProperty requestProp = getRequestProperties();
String item = requestProp.getString("item");
int itemQty = Integer.parseInt(requestProp.getString("qty"));
```

followed by your businees logic.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the context in which you need the parameter values, so I'll assume you're writing the business logic for a Controller Command.

When a controller command is instantiated by the runtime framework, it will invoke the `setRequestProperties()` method, passing in a `TypedProperties` instance, which contains the request parameters (whether passed as GET or POST parameters, mapped from an XML message, or through the REST layer).

The default implementation of this (in `com.ibm.commerce.commands.ControllerCommandImpl`) will simply store this in the `requestProperties` attribute from which you can then access it in, say, `performExecute()`.

I usually recommend people to override `setRequestProperties()` to pick out the values they want there and store them in instance variables, though.

Don't forget to validate the parameters in validateParameters().

Refer to the [Creating business logic](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.tutorial.doc/tutorial/ttd09.htm) tutorial in the Knowledge Center for a more thorough walk-through.